# Not a Number (NaN) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to add up my sum and charge respectively. But when i alert `sum + charge`, i get NaN. why is this happening?

```
   <script>
        sum = 0;
        charge = 0;

$('.panel').append(
        '<div class="container" style=" font-size:14px; "> '+ 

        '<table style="width:100%;" class="table" id="tables">'+


'<td  class="name" >'+std.name+'</td>'+
'<td><p class="total" ><span class="min-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p></td>'+
'</table>'+
'</div>'

    $('.panel').on('keyup','.quantity',function()

       container = $(this).closest('div');

       quantity = Number($(this).val());
       price = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));         
       container.find(".min-total span").text(quantity * price);

        sum = 0;

           $(".sum-total").each(function(){
           sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
           })  
     }

        $('.charge').on('keyup','.charge',function(){
                $('.charge span').text( Number($(this).val()));
                charge = Number($(this).val());

         alert(sum + charge);


        </script>
```

Comment: Please add complete code to reproduce your problem

Comment: Probably `Number()` isn't converting some text value to a number. It's impossible for us to say where, though, without a more comprehensive example. You can add [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) tests at every point to set values to zero when this happens.

Comment: One or both of the fields contains something that's not numeric and can't be converted to a number by `Number`. You either fix that or replace everything except numbers before calling `Number` over it. A possible cause could be usage of comma's in your fields.

Comment: `$(this).val()` implies that `.charge` is a form field of some kind. But, then you have `$('.charge span')` which indicates that there is a `span` as a descendant of that form field, which is unlikely since most form fields do not have child content.

Comment: Try outputting the values of `sum` and `alert` separately to figure out which one is not a number. For example `alert(sum);alert(charge);`

Comment: @HectorCorrea, okay so after alerting, it is sum which is `undefined`

Comment: @BlindSniper, it is sum which is giving undefined

Comment: @BlindSniper `alert()`s can be troublesome in debugging because of their blocking behavior. Instead logging to the `console` is much preferred.

Comment: Instead of replying to comments, why don't you simply do what the first comment asks and edit your question to include the additional relevant code so we can definitively answer your question?

Comment: Now that you know that `sum` is not what you expected, try outputting the value of `$(this).text()` inside the call to `each` to see if the problem are those values or the result of your `Number()` function.

Comment: @HectorCorrea, kindly check my update now

Comment: @ScottMarcus i have included the complete code now

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal, please look into my update

Comment: You are trying to get the `val()` of an element that doesn't have one.

Comment: You still haven't provided ALL of the relevant code for us to help you. Show us the HTML as well. Where's `.panel`, `.quantity`, `.charge` and `.price`?

Answer (score -1):

The wikipedia definition says:

> In computing, NaN, standing for not a number, is a numeric data type
>   value representing an undefined or unrepresentable value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

In your code either `$(this).text()` or `$(this).val()` cannot be computed by Number() and return `NaN`. Make sure the value of those is either a Number or a string made of numbers.

Comment: Yes, but that really doesn't explain where the `NaN` is coming from. Without more code, no one can provide an accurate answer.

Comment: The question is " why is this happening?"

Comment: And, there is no way to know for sure because we don't have enough informaiton.

Comment: We can explain how it can happen (so can the documentation), but we can't explain why it is happening here.